# Converting hexadecimal to byte in php

Tags: php, type-conversion, byte, hex

I am very new to PHP

I want to create a byte array something like this (in Java):

```
byte array[] = { (byte) 0x9C, (byte) 0xA0};
```

How do I do it in PHP? Any syntactical help highly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "hexadecimal to byte"? 
I am going to assume you mean "... to decimal".

The result of `0x3f` when output will be automatically converted to a decimal number. In internal calculations, it will be converted automatically if needed - you can do

```
$myvar = 300 + 0xfa;
```

without problems.

You can cast a variable to an integer using `(int)$varname` or `(int)value` but it doesn't really make sense in your case. A byte is a byte, whether you express its value as `0x3F` or `63`.

To convert hexadecimal to decimal, there is also
[hexdec()](http://www.php.net/hexdec)

> Returns the decimal equivalent of the hexadecimal number represented by the hex_string argument. hexdec() converts a hexadecimal string to a decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

How about [pack function](http://php.net/pack)?